# Write a trigger that fires before an update of loc on the dept table and ensures that every employee in the department gets a 5% raise

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using the Scott/tiger account how do you resolve this pl/sql trigger script?

Write a trigger that fires before an update of loc on the dept table and ensures that every  employee in the department gets a 5% raise.

Answer (score 2):

I have racked my brain thinking of the nicest way to put this.

Did you see any of the "SAW" movies? Neither did I, but we all know the premise. Let's just say you should cut off your own foot rather than do what you are trying to do.

Triggers have two basic purposes. One is to act as a high-level check constraint, to check data manipulation to verify the results are valid. The other is to log the operations they are responsible for.

Never, and I don't know how much more emphasis I can place here, use a trigger as an embedded OK button to execute some function completely unrelated to the triggering action. Or even related.

In your particular instance, if you want to give everyone in a department a raise, write a script or stored procedure to give everyone in a department a raise -- *after* it verifies the user executing the script or stored procedure has the requisite privileges to do so.

Suppose a department needs to change its `loc` but not give everyone a raise? Suppose everyone finds out that just by changing the `loc` of their department, they magically get a raise? Shoot, change it to something weird and then issue another `update` to change it back. Boom -- 10% raise.

I once interviewed at a company and the IT manager told me "I don't allow triggers on any table." I thought that was just about the most asinine thing I'd ever heard a supposedly intelligent person say. But if he had people writing triggers like the one you propose, I guess I can see his point. Still a horrible over-reaction, but at least it would be based on an actual fear.

Even if you're just playing around -- learning how to write triggers, learn how to write triggers *correctly*. Don't develop bad habits you'll have to unlearn while looking for a new job.

Comment: I totally understand the purpose of triggers.  They act as security to the database.  I found it weird that we had to do this question but it was to see how we tackle on a problem.  Its not my fault that I was asked to do this, and I don't think I should give the prof crap for teaching something so unapplicable.  Nevertheless its what was asked of us and luckly I figured it out regardless how rediculous of a question it was.  Man that Saw thing. That was funny.. Thanks. Please answer the question before just commenting on how non-theoretical something is.

Comment: Well, then that makes your question "I have a homework assignment to write a trigger. Can someone please write it for me?" That *is* your fault.

Answer (score 0):

create or replace trigger updateLoc
   before update of loc on dept
   for each row
   begin
           for nrec in (select * from emp where deptno =:old.deptno) loop
           update emp set sal = (nrec.sal * 1.05) where deptno= nrec.deptno;
           end loop;
   end;
/